# Android - Unable to view image saved in new directory when I try to upload it again

Tags: java, android, photo-upload

I am uploading a image from gallery and saving it into new directory after cropping it (using Android-image-cropper library).

The directory is getting created and image is getting saved successfully.
It can be found in File Explorer, but when I try upload the same image in the app it is not showing up.

I also tried saving the image in existing directory, the directory is visible in the search and not the image in it, but it can be found in File Explorer.

**EditActivity**

```
save_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveImage();
                }
        });
    }

public void saveImage(){
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(resultUri);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+"/Pictures/");
        if(!dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        File f = new File(dir,System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90,outputStream);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),f.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            outputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**MainActivity**

```
    private void cam_permission() {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
        } else{
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    }


    private  void storage_permission(){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
        } else{
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gallery, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permission is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Storage Permission is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                File file = new File(currentPhotoPath);
                Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent .setClass(MainActivity.this,  EditActivity.class);
                intent .putExtra("imageUri", contentUri.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contentUri = data.getData();
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent .setClass(MainActivity.this,  EditActivity.class);
                intent .putExtra("imageUri", contentUri.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }



    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: If you are using Android 11 or higher device, you will have to use new method to access the file.

Comment: `if(!dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdirs();
        }` That should be `if(!dir.exists()){
           if (!dir.mkdirs()) return;
        }`. Also display a Toast to inform the user.

Comment: `I try upload the same image in the app it is not showing up` I dont know what you mean with showing up. But if your app can create an image file somewhere then it can always use and read that file to upload or what ever to do with it. So why cant you use the same path? Tell it without us needing to read all that code.

Comment: I have a button to choose an image from gallery. After editing the image it is saved as new image in the given directory. It can be found in file explorer, but I want to saved choose the image from gallery on button click, but it is not showing up.